# Changing the attributes of the Jquery UI Accordion script

Tags: jquery, attributes, accordion

My code is below. It works with just one attribute: **header**.

However, I'd also like to change the **heightStyle** attribute from "auto" to "content".

...But when I try to add the **heightStyle** attribute the whole thing seems to break down.

Here's the original, which works:

```
/* Accordion effect with just one attribute customized*/
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        header:"h6"
    });
  });
```

When I try to add the **heightStyle** attribute, like below, nothing works. I lose the accordion effect completely.  What am I doing wrong?

```
/* Accordion effect with two custom attributes */
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        header:"h6"
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "," to separate options.

```
/* Accordion effect with two custom attributes */
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        header:"h6",
        heightStyle:"content"
    });
  });
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you! :^)